# Can't sum elements of array using loop

Tags: arrays, ruby, loops

```
arr = Array.new(3)# { Array.new(3) }
sum = 0
for i in 0..2
  for j in 0..2
    print "[#{i},#{j}] = "
    arr[i]=Integer(gets)
    sum+=arr[i,j]#Error here: in `+': Array can't be coerced into Fixnum (TypeError)
  end
end
puts "sum = #{sum}"
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately it is not clear what are you asking about - please provide more information like desired result etc.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `arr[i,j]` use the following syntax to get a value from a nested array:

```
arr[i][j]
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some logic issues in your code.

Here is a code to read a 2-D array

```
arr = []
for i in 0..2
  a = []
  for j in 0..2
    print "[#{i},#{j}] = "
    a << Integer(gets)
  end
  arr << a
end
```

Once you have 2-D array, you can sum it like below

```
sum = 0
for i in 0...arr.size
  for j in 0...arr[i].size
    sum += arr [i][j]
  end
end

p sum
```

In Ruby, the sum part can also be done with built-in methods using something like below:

```
p arr.flatten.reduce(:+)
```